# Is there an open-source alternative to Windows compound files?

Tags: c++, windows, open-source, containers, compound-file

I'm trying to save a couple of files to a container file. The files can be modified later which means the container might have to be enlarged. The user should only see this container as a single file in the file system. The application is written in C++ and running on Windows, but the files should be portable to other platforms as well.

The requirements for the container format are:
1. *Size*: Allow files bigger than 4GB.
2. *Portability*: It should be feasible to open the container files on other platforms.
3. *Performance*: When changing a file inside the container, only the "chunks" that represent that specific file may be changed. Especially, there may not be a complete rewrite of that file.
4. *Structure*: It should provide a directory structure that allows to build a hierarchy of files and directories.

When leaving out requirement 1.) and 2.) compound files (like used by Word and Excel) are a good fit.

Of course, it's possible to design an API that fulfills all the requirements, but I wonder if there is already some open-source solution that tackles the very problem?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Is the HDF5 File Format what you are looking for if you are building an application in C++

Answer (score 1):

A google search for "portable structured storage" yielded: [pole](http://pole.berlios.de/)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I do not want to use compound files, just something with a similar concept.
BTW, pole and pole++ both seem to be unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

Some archive format (zip, bzip2) might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To extend J.F. Sebastian's answer, `tar` might be a better format due to it not compressing. It's literally just a container.

I'm not certain how any of these archive formats are at being editable though. Have a play with [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) and find out, I guess =)

Comment: You can store files in zip format without any compression (other archive formats might also support uncompressed storage).