# Open source embedded filesystem (or single file virtual filesystem, or structured storage) library for C

Tags: c, open-source, cross-platform, filesystems, compound-file

I'm not sure what the "general" name of something like this might be. I'm looking for a library that gives me a file format to store different types of binary data in an expanding single file.

- open source, non-GPL (LGPL ok)
- C interface
- the file format is a single file
- multiple files within using a POSIX-like file API (or multiple "blobs" within using some other API)
- file/structure editing is done in-place
- reliable first, performant second

Examples include:

- the virtual drives of a virtual machine
- [whefs](http://fossil.wanderinghorse.net/repos/whefs/index.cgi/wiki/whefs)
- [HDF](http://www.hdfgroup.org/)
- [CDF](http://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/)
- [NetCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/)

Problems with the above:

- whefs doesn't appear to be very mature, but best describes what I'm after
- HDF, CDF, NetCDF are usable (also very reliable and fast), but they're rather complicated and I'm not entirely convinced of their support for opaque binary "blobs"

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention, one other relevant question:
[Simple Virtual Filesystem in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361560/simple-virtual-filesystem-in-c-c)
Another similar question:
[Is there an open-source alternative to Windows compound files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374417/is-there-an-open-source-alternative-to-windows-compound-files)

**Edit:**
Added condition of in-place editing.

**Edit:**
whefs superseded by: [whio_epfs](http://whiki.wanderinghorse.net/wikis/whio/?page=whio_epfs)

Comment: ROOT (http://root.cern.ch/) implements such a thing in it's TFile format, but that is c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to do what I was looking for: [libgsf](http://directory.fsf.org/project/libgsf/)

Still need to test its reliability/performance and how cross-platform the binary format is.

Comment: Isn't it just for archives like gzip? What kind of virtual filesystem does libgsf support?

Comment: It supports GZip, but the use case here was more for support of this format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942138.aspx

Comment: Understood. One last question: What do you think about POLE? And does libgsf even create such OLE container with a fixed size, finally?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that format and saw no mention of it in the libgsf docs.

Comment: SQLite (http://sqlite.org/) will do the job in a robust way, with added relational sauce should you require it.

Comment: @MikeW I thought of it as well, but at the time this question was written, it didn't perform well enough for my use case.

Comment: @Ioan: well the requirement put "performance second" ....

Comment: @MikeW Yes it did; that's why I mentioned for my use case. There was a minimum, even for secondary requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about the Linux loopback device, which lets you treat a file on a filesystem as a first-class block device (and then proceed to mkfs, mount, etc.)

(What sort of platform are you targetting? A fully-featured Unixlike? Something in the embedded space with a small footprint?)

Comment: Cross-platform is the intent. Certainly Windows and an embedded Linux version. I considered the loopback device, but didn't mention it because I wasn't sure whether it could grow in size and it won't work on Windows.

Comment: Right. If I were in your shoes, then, I'd also be looking into the various log-structured filesystems to see if there was one with an acceptable license which you could hack up well enough to work in userland and to work off a file as backing store (as opposed to a block device).

Answer (score 0):

The WxWindows library supports ZIP files (see [http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxarc.html#wxarc)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxarc.html#wxarc).
This has also the advantage that you can look at the contents using a ZIP manager (e.g. WINZIP).

A commercial alternative is ChillKat (http://www.chilkatsoft.com/)

If security is a concern, encrypt the file contents and mangle the file names in the ZIP archive.

Comment: Security isn't a concern. I haven't looked into normal archive types too much, but I wonder how well they perform with regards to large data sets, high speed, random access of the internal file contents, and simultaneous reader/writer...

Answer (score 0):

Eet library from the Enlightenment project maybe?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_Foundation_Libraries#EET 
http://docs.enlightenment.org/api/eet/html/

Comment: Nice idea, but not mature yet. It depends on Eina which is currently unstable. Also, it basically stores a hash map of "chunks", which requires an extra layer to manage them.

Comment: The Ogg container format is also very similar to Eet in simplicity: http://www.xiph.org/ogg/doc/

Answer (score 0):

What about [BerkeleyDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB)? It's not exactly a filesystem but it's quite transparent to store 'binary data' in a file. License seems to be quite permissive as well.

Comment: According to http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/berkeley-db/htdocs/licensing.html it requires a commercial license for closed-source applications. Also, I don't know how much faster it is than SQLite, which was a few times slower than simply storing directly to a file. This was a simple test, batch commit to store data.

Comment: Well you did not mention you were doing a closed-source application. And yes, it might be just ike SQLite, but with a few more years of stability on the embedded side.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading. The current BerkeleyDB open-source license is GPL-like (as in, it requires your entire application source be released), violating one of the requirements I mentioned in the question.