# Emulation file system (Windows)

Tags: c, windows

Please, advise me SDK for emulating a file system? (Windows)

Thanks.

Comment: Emulating it on a different platform? Abstracting it so your unit tests are fast? Emulating NTFS on FAT32? We're going to need more information on what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe this old question helps although I did not get the answer I was hoping for: [open-source-compound-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374417/is-there-an-open-source-alternative-to-windows-compound-files)

Comment: Depending on what you really mean in your question, you could define a ram drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 2008: Virtual file system(like FUSE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689048/windows-2008-virtual-file-systemlike-fuse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities of applications for windows . I'm using [boxedapp](http://www.boxedapp.com/).

Comment: Thank you! problem is solved.

Comment: +1 great app! emulates not only files but also registry!

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at resources from OSR, they have a [file system development kit](http://www.osr.com/fsdk.html) and many other resources to help you write the drivers necessary.